# Проект на next.js закрывается после запуска

Tags: nextjs, next.js, next

столкнулся со странной проблемой. Запускаю проект на vds командой npm run dev, после запроса странички, она компилируется, отдается (через nginx запрос перенаправляется на локально запущенный проект), после этого начинается компиляция страницы not found (иногда успевает закончиться) и процесс сам завершается.

```
# npm run dev

> maksim_aksenov@0.1.0 dev
> next dev

   ▲ Next.js 14.0.4
   - Local:        http://localhost:3000

 ✓ Ready in 2s
 ○ Compiling / ...
 ✓ Compiled / in 2s (577 modules)
 ○ Compiling /not-found ...
root@...:~/next-project#
```

Также если попробовать сделать билд проекта, получаю такое сообщение:

```
Creating an optimized production build  ...Killed
```

Попробовал сделать обычный проект с помощью create-next-app и с ним такой проблемы не возникло.

На моих устройствах с виндой таких проблем вообще не наблюдается.

Надеюсь на вашу помощь, заранее спасибо!

Comment: у меня нечто подобное было на виртуальном хостинге из-за нехватки ресурсов. изначально я видел только это сообщение без последнего слова, поскольку запускал под файлменеджером. когда запустил в чисом терминале, то увидел сообщение об ошибке и указание где ее исправить.

Comment: @romanown Да, проблема была в нехватке ОЗУ на сервере, на 3 гб все собралось. "Решил" проблему сборкой локально, сэкономил) Правда дошел я до этого методом тыка, никаких сообщений не было(